# how to debug a $result

Tags: php

first i  have to debug a php script and i m not a php developer
i would want to have the result of **$result** variable in a specific file as **/tmp/logging.log**

```
 $result = $this->executeCommand("git status --branch ");
```

for a simple variable as **$path** i found how to get the value with **file_put_contents**

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/config.log', print_r( $path, true ));
```

could you tell me how to log the value of  **$result** or even **$this** in a specific file?

thank you very much guy and have a nice week-end :)

Comment: You may use `var_dump($result)` or `pr($result)`

Comment: if i do that where i can find the log ?

Comment: Have you tried running the same statement (`file_put_contents(... $path ...)`) with the `$result`-variable?

Comment: when i try that file_put_contents('/tmp/config.log',  $result );  i've nothing on my log file it's blank

Comment: Why are you debugging by writing things to a file? Note that `executeCommand` is not a function in CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

When you get no output in the log-file at all, it's probably because `$result` is either `false` or `null`. The command `var_dump` will give you more information on that than `print_r` does. Unfortunately `var_dump` has no extra option to return the output, so you have to use output buffering.

```
ob_start(); // Start output-buffering
var_dump($result); // Dump the variable (normally sent to browser, but output buffering will pick it up)
$debugInfo = ob_get_clean(); // Stop output-buffering, store output in $debugInfo
file_put_contents('/tmp/debug.log', $debugInfo);
```